# How to best create sensor classes and assign properties (derived from sensor context) to them in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not a coder. But just started playing with tech. I am seeking advice in how to best approach this:

**My situation**: In a park, there are a couple of sensors that can detect events (whether it be motion, or (2G) cell-phone activity or anything else.. does not really matter. The important thing is, they can detect something). Now, each sensor is special because it is located at a specific location in the park and what is present at that specific contextual space, says something valuable about the kind of event that is detected from that sensor. For instance, if a sensor is located at the corner in the park, or if a sensor is located at a location in where there is a water (lake), or if a sensor is located near an entrance of a shop/store. One could consider these things contextual-properties of a sensor.

So I want to document this in Python. But I am not familiar with coding or Python. So I did some reading and what I think would be the way forward is:

> Make a class for each sensor, and assign properties to that sensor
>   class that describe the contextual-properties.

Something like:

```
Class sensor_1_2
    corner: true
    shop: true
    lake: false
```

I will need this, to reference, as I am collecting events and wish to be able to say something about the kind of events that are outputted from the sensors. So let's say for a certain timestamp, a sensor on the grid show some value. Then I want to be able to assign some sort of severity to that detection, by referencing the properties of the sensor. (I have outputted a CSV file with synthetic data, that shows sensor activity over time, given the static routes. 
)

**My question: is my python approach a good approach? if not, what would be a better approach. I mean, would my example above be even a good way to assign properties? Or should I first create a set of variables of properties?**

Important: I only want to do this in the language of Python.

Comment: You might want to look into wireless sensor networks before going into this. I guess you're gonna use battery operated micro controllers to do so?

Usually you program those in C or C++. For some of them it is possible to run some simplified version of python but I have no idea why you would do this, since all the libraries and plugins supplied by the manufacturer or third parties will be written in C/C++.

Comment: I would use a `class` for sensors of the same type, and initialize its attributes per `instance`. You could reasonably use inheritance, creating a parent generic `Sensor` class first, and then specialize via inheritance.

Comment: @sal that sounds interesting, I will investigate this further. Thanks Could you perhaps provide a sample code? Per indication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a *class* per sensor *type*, and store the context-properties in individual *instances* representing each a very specific sensor. Using *inheritance* you can group the common methods and attributes in a parent class (called for example `Sensors`), and then inherit sub-classes from it for each specific sensor type.

```
# Keep common attributes and methods in the parent class
class Sensor(object):
    def __init__(self, name, context={}):
        self.name = name
        self.context = context  # dictionary that contains context-properties

    @property
    def ability(self):
        return None

    def calculate_severity(self):
        # calculate
        severity_value = 1  # mock
        return severity_value


# Inherit by sensor type and override specific attributes/methods
class MotionSensor(Sensor):
    @property
    def ability(self):
        return 'Motion'


# Inherit by sensor type and override specific attributes/methods
class Cell2GSensor(Sensor):
    @property
    def ability(self):
        return '2G'


# Individual sensors are instances of the relevant class
motion_sensor_1 = MotionSensor('park001', {'corner': True, 'shop': True, 'lake': False})
motion_sensor_2 = MotionSensor('park002', {'corner': False, 'shop': False, 'lake': True})
cell_sensor_1 = Cell2GSensor('cell001', {'corner': False, 'shop': False, 'lake': True})
cell_sensor_2 = Cell2GSensor('cell002', {'corner': False, 'shop': True, 'lake': True})

# You could also just have a list with all sensors, and iterate
all_sensors = [motion_sensor_1, motion_sensor_2, cell_sensor_1, cell_sensor_2]

for sensor in all_sensors:
    print('This is sensor:', sensor.name, ', I sense: ', sensor.ability)
```

Keep in mind that methods and attributes in all of these depend on how you will use them, which is not specified here. It can greatly change based on whether these instances are supposed to run on the sensors, or if they are created while parsing a csv log with the aggregate output of each sensor.